# No module named 'grp' error while importing helper function

Tags: import, error-handling, grpc, python-3.7, helper

I am trying to run the below command in python 3.7.3 in my windows laptop but facing the 'No module named 'grp'' error

```
import helper
```

[image]

Comment: Your question lacks detail and appears to be an issue with the `helper` library rather than a programming question per se. You may wish to contact the [project](https://pypi.org/project/helper/) maintainers and have them help you.

Answer (score 0):

I've been through the same problem when working on a project. But it seems you just need a recent version of celery.
The following code worked for me.

```
pip install celery==5.2.0
```

After all, you can try a more recent version of celery.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the original environment you migrated had a local file called helper.py.  When you noticed it was missing you installed it from pypi and that is a different version and maybe not fully baked.

In my case I tried to get my Udacity environment duplicated on my box and got this same issue.  I found the modules that were in the environment originally running it had the file in the run folder.

So I pip uninstalled helper, created a new helper folder in the active site-packages folder, and copied the Udacity helper file there.  After that it imported without any error.